# Android text veiw in linear layout

Tags: android, layout

I am having trouble placing two textveiw below each other. I tried using 
android:Layout_below="@+id/title" but the second textview always gets placed far off and not below first text view. How do I place the two textveiws exactly below each other?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#453b4da7"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:text="loading City"
                android:textColor="#FF040404"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:text="Loading Locality"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="10dip" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Giving more information will allow the community to better help you with your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a vertical LinearLayout

Comment: It was really simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You used to linear layout and have different orientation. Just give orientation vertical to linear layout and put image view in another linear layout that should be horizontal with a vertical linear layout.
Pseudo code is like this

```
Linear layout horizontal
 Child 1 : Image View
 Child 2 : Linear layout vertical
          c1: text view
          c2: text view
```

Hope this will helpful and sorry if pseudo code is not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#453b4da7"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:text="loading City"
                android:textColor="#FF040404"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ThumbnailView"
                android:text="Loading Locality"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="10dip" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```